# how to determine with php that INSERT IGNORE is passed?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check, that if this code

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE 
    INTO `popupip` (`userid` ,`ownerid`,`ip` ,`date` ,`ref`) 
    VALUES ('$secid', $ownerid, '$date' , '$ref');"
);
```

has inserted to table, to do some work.

```
if (condition) {
    // is not duplicated and I should pay to him/her
} else {
    // is duplicated an I shouldn't pay to him/her
}
```

what I should put in for `condition` ?

note: combination of `userid` ,`ownerid`,`ip` ,`date` are UNIQUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should cover you for SQL errors and duplicate entries.

```
  if(mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error()))
    {
          if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1){
           //insert took place
           }else{
           //no insert
           }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_affected_rows` function could help you there. You can put mysql_affected_rows() in your condition to check if there were any rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) and check if the rows inserted are more than one.
But as you will see in the link the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and its [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) method.

Comment: I have a huge database with race condition . can i still user mysql_affected_rows ?

Comment: If it's being used for this query only, I suppose you could. But you may add this to your question, if you want a more complete answer.

Comment: See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).